# Is it true that $\Bbb{E}(X_\infty)=\Bbb{E}(X_0)$ if $X$ is a martingale?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

> Let us consider a martingale $(X_n)_n$. Let me assume that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n=X_\infty$ exists a.s. and in $L^1$.

My question is, is it then always true that $\Bbb{E}(X_\infty)=\Bbb{E}(X_0)$? I would say it is true if there exists $Y\in L^1$ such that $|X_n|\leq Y$ because then we can apply DCT and get that $\Bbb{E}(X_\infty)=\lim_n \Bbb{E}(X_n)$ and since $X_n$ is a martingale we know that $\Bbb{E}(X_n)=\Bbb{E}(X_0)$ and we are done.

Is it furthermore true that I need the two assumptions that the limit exists a.s. and in $L^1$ if one fails I cannot use the DCT. But if I for example have that the limit exists in $L^p$ then my proof would also work right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $Y_n \to Y$ in $L^{1}$ then $|EY_n-EY|\leq E|Y_n-Y| \to 0$, so $EY_n \to EY$.
2. If $(X_n)$ is  martingale then $EX_n=EX_0$ for all $n$.

Once you have $L^{1}$ convergence you don't have to use DCT and you don't have to use almost sure convergence.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your answer with respect to my questions. What does this now mean. Is it true what I said?

Comment: @user123234 Yes, and I have proved it.

Comment: Is your $Y_n$ equal to my $X_n$ or not?

Comment: @user123234 Take $Y_n=X_n$ and $Y=X_{\infty}$.

Comment: but so we don't need such a $Y$ as in my question to apply DCT?

Comment: Yes, DCT is too much for this question. Definition of $L^{1}$ convergence is enough.  A.s. convergence is also not needed.  @user123234

Comment: Ah and we also do not need a.s. convergence?

Comment: But if we would like to apply DCT then we need a.s. convergence and also my random variable $Y$ right? But this is more demanding.

Answer (score 2):

**Question**: is $\Bbb{E}(X_\infty)=\Bbb{E}(X_0)$ if $X_n$ is martingale and $X_n \to X$ a.s. and $X \in L_1$?

**Answer**. No. Consider $X_n = 2^n \prod_{i=1}^n \xi_i$ where $\xi_n$ are i.i.d. $Bern(\frac12)$. Hence $X_n \to X = 0$ a.s., $\mathbf{E}X_n = 1 \nrightarrow 0 = \mathbf{E}X$.

**Statement**. If $X_n$ is martingale and $X_n \to X$ in $L_1$ hence almost sure limit $\lim_n X_n$ exists and coincides with $X$. Hence there are extra conditions in OP.

Comment: For what is this no the answer?

Comment: $L^{1}$ convergence is part of the hypothesis.

Comment: This is not my assumption my assumption is $X_n\rightarrow X$ a.s. and $X_n\rightarrow X$ in $L^1$

Comment: @geetha290krm I looks like $X \in L_1$. It don't looks like there's $L_1$ convergence and with $L_1$ convergence the problem is much simplier.

Comment: @user123234 Ok then it's not an answer to the original question.

Comment: $X_n \to X_{\infty}$ a.s. and in $L^{1}$ is a standard way of saying that the convergence holds in both senses.

Comment: @geetha290krm But in this sence it's strange. Because if we already have $L_1$ convergence then we already have a.s. convernge. I just supposed that OP doesn't imply extra conditions.

Comment: I don't think $L^p$ convergence imply a.s. convergence does it?

Comment: @user123234 in general it doesn't imply it. But we have martingales and it changes the situation.